# Получение актуальной информации из окна программы

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Добрый день. Столкнулся с необходимостью получения информации о текущем треке из Winamp или AIMP.
На просторах интернета обнаружил нужный мне пример.
Вот собственно весь класс:

```
public class CurrentTrack
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, string lpString, int cch);

    const string lpClassName = "Winamp v1.x";
    const string strTtlEnd = " - Winamp";

    public string GetSongTitle()
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(lpClassName, null);
        if (hwnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) return "Not running";

        string lpText = new string((char)0, 100);
        int intLength = GetWindowText(hwnd, lpText, lpText.Length);

        if ((intLength <= 0) || (intLength > lpText.Length)) return "unknown";

        string strTitle = lpText.Substring(0, intLength);
        int intName = strTitle.IndexOf(strTtlEnd);
        int intLeft = strTitle.IndexOf("[");
        int intRight = strTitle.IndexOf("]");

        if ((intName >= 0) && (intLeft >= 0) && (intName < intLeft) &&
            (intRight >= 0) && (intLeft + 1 < intRight))
            return strTitle.Substring(intLeft + 1, intRight - intLeft - 1);

        if ((strTitle.EndsWith(strTtlEnd)) && (strTitle.Length > strTtlEnd.Length))
            strTitle = strTitle.Substring(0, strTitle.Length - strTtlEnd.Length);

        int intDot = strTitle.IndexOf(".");
        if ((intDot > 0) && IsNumeric(strTitle.Substring(0, intDot)))
            strTitle = strTitle.Remove(0, intDot + 1);

        return strTitle.Trim();
    }

    private bool IsNumeric(string Value)
    {
        try
        {
            double.Parse(Value);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

На форме у меня пока есть лейбл, как выводить актуальный трек правильно в него? Пробовал вызывать функцию `public string GetSongTitle()` через цикл `while`
Но ничего не показывает. Или пустота или трек который уже проиграл. Как привести в рабочее состояние все это?
UPD. Вопрос решился  вот таким кодом

```
 private async void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       while(true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            label1.Text = track.GetSongTitle();
        }
    }
```

Но совет все же требуется. Правильно ли я вызываю или можно лучше сделать?

Comment: Правильно с какой точки зрения? Программа будет постоянно потреблять процессорное время (независимо от того, видимо окно или свернуто). Если это допустимо, других существенных проблем с кодом вроде нет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight а как оптимально получать нужные мне значения из плеера?

Comment: Оптимальнее - через api, которое этот плеер представляет. Например, написать плагин для плеера и передавать информацию из него.